# Заменить одномерный на двумерный массив

Tags: c++, массивы, шахматы

Столкнулся с трудностью. Задача состоит в том, чтобы расположить 8 ферзей так, чтобы они не были под ударом друг друга. Мне нужно реализовать данную задачу с помощью двумерного массива. У меня получилось только с одномерным.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int q[8] = {};
    bool ok;
    for (int c = 1; c != 8; c++)
    {
        q[c] = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            if (++q[c] == 8)
            {
                if (--c == -1) { 
                    c = c - 1; 
                }
                continue;
            }
            ok = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
                if ((q[i] == q[c]) || ((c - i) == abs(q[c] - q[i])))
                {
                    ok = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (ok) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "---------------------------------";
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (j == q[i]) {
                cout << "| Q ";
            }
            else {
                cout << "|   ";
            }
        }
        cout << "|";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "---------------------------------";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, зачем? ну заведите `int q[8][8]`, например, и везде, где пишете `q[i]`, теперь пишите `q[0][i]`. Вот вам и двумерный массив. Странно, обычно ценится решение с меньшим количеством памяти...

Comment: Так требует преподаватель.

Comment: @arnold думаю, что одна из причин по которой вам еще не помогли - абсолютно нечитаемый код. Рекомендую заняться этим вопросом, чтобы вам могли помочь те, кто ваш код видят впервые. Думаю ваш преподаватель тоже не сможет ничего понять в этих названиях переменных

Comment: Понимаете, если всерьез — то это будет совершенно иная программа, на ином принципе построенная... Ваше решение использует массив координат; препод же, видимо, хочет увидеть тупое решение, в котором в массиве могут быть только 0 или 1 — есть там ферзь или нет. А это уже не простая переделка одномерного массива в двумерный...

Comment: @Harry я Вас понял. Уже работаю над этим вопросом